# Можно ли напрямую в функцию передать массив?

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, случайные-числа

Функция выдаёт случайные числа в определённом диапазоне с исключением. Исключений может быть сколько угодно.

```
int randint (int min, int max, int exceptions{}) { ... }
```

Как мне написать параметры функции, чтобы я мог вызывать функцию таким образом:

```
randint (0, 10, {4, 5, 6});
```

Мне нужна именно передача массива напрямую.

Comment: Для передачи массива в функцию используются указатели. Других вариантов нет

Comment: Жаль, было бы удобно передавать исключения таким образом. А так надо создавать временный массив с исключениями и его уже передавать, не очень-то и удобно :(

Comment: Передавайте `initializer_list`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможны несколько вариантов:

```
int randint (int min, int max, ::std::initializer_list<int> values)

int randint (int min, int max, ::std::array<int, 3> values)

int randint (int min, int max, ::std::array_view<int> values) // аналог gsl::span
```

Использовать указатели для передачи массива в функцию не следует.

Comment: а почему "Использовать указатели для передачи массива в функцию не следует"? Это фундаментально! В Си, например (прямом предке С++) это единственно возможный вариант. (Да и согласно вопросу - для С++ тоже)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Ну так правильно, это пришло из С, где это единственный вариант. Однако в С++ имеются лучшие альтернативы. Собственно сырые указатели на данные в С++ теперь нужны разве что как сырые итераторы (и то, лучше сделать обертку) и для взаимодействия с кодом на С. см [CppCoreGuidelines](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#alternative-2)

Comment: Но согласно вопросу: "Можно ли напрямую в функцию передать массив" - это разве не лучший вариант? У нас есть последовательность байт, указатель на начало которой мы и передаем в функцию.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, массив нельзя просто передать как указатель, нужно ещё передавать размер переданного массива. Поэтому в этом нет никакого смысла, когда есть нормальные C++ решения (`array` и `array_view`). VTT, в std нет класса `array_view`

Comment: Я бы вместо `std::array<int, 3> values` предложил `std::vector<int> values`, а то ведь автор пишет, что размер заранее неизвестен.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Нет, это не лучший вариант. Вместе с указателем на первый элемент массива надо еще передать размер массива, еще, возможно, сделать аннотацию для статической верификации и конечно не перепутать это все в теле функции. А так все будет аккуратно передаваться в одном параметре без лишних телодвижений.

Comment: @ixSci Это понятно, но вопрос стоял не в том, какие есть удобные методы передачи различных массивов в функцию - а в том как это сделать на прямую! Что касается размера - это уже забота программиста: он может использовать фиксированный размер или передавать его вместе с указателем

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Вариант №2 передает массив напрямую (в отличие от передачи указателя).

Comment: @ixSci Ну да, `array_view` почему-то не включили в окончательный вариант С++17, но смысл класса вроде как понятен и есть куча аналогов вроде `gsl::span`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, программисты беспечны. Нельзя не передавать массив, это рассадник ошибок. Да и передача размера, как правило, не меньший рассадник. C++ был создан из-за недостатков С, нет никакого смысла не использовать достоинства C++, используя наследие C, которое существует только потому, что нужно сохранять обратную совместимость.

Comment: @VTT, ага, смысл ясен, но с SO обычно copy-past делают и получат ошибку. Просто было бы неплохо упомянуть, что такое существует, но нет в стандартной библиотеке.

Comment: @ixSci я полностью согласен. НО!!! Вопрос то был.

Comment: А как мне получить доступ к элементам initializer_list? exceptions[i] и exceptions(i) не работают.

Comment: @Mournehowl `exceptions.begin()[i]`. А размер брать из `exceptions.size()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо.